# How to convert ODT files to PDF in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdf-generation, odf

Him

I'm using odf-reports gem (https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report) to populate an odt template I have. But then I want to convert it to PDF.

They advise to use libreoffice to do the conversion, and that works locally, but I want to use it in Heroku.

Anyone know how can I do this conversion on heroku?

Thank you

Comment: did you found another solution?